# Is there a way to install windows 7 without the new 100mb hidden partition it is adding by default?

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can the Windows 7 system reserved partition be deleted without problems?](https://superuser.com/questions/74980/can-the-windows-7-system-reserved-partition-be-deleted-without-problems)

Is there a way to install windows 7 without the new 100mb hidden partition it is adding by default?
What is that partition even for?
I have an environment that makes it so I can't have that partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That partition is the "System Reserved" partition, and is used for Bitlocker and as a safe place to keep the boot and WinPE files that may be needed for recovery in case of a disaster.

See Molly's answer here: [Can the Windows 7 system reserved partition be deleted without problems?](https://superuser.com/questions/74980/can-the-windows-7-system-reserved-partition-be-deleted-without-problems/74996#74996)

Comment: WinRE vs WinPE correct?

Answer (score 0):

When Windows create two partitions for you, delete the second one. Then extend first one (100 MB one) to size you wish for.