# PC does not boot detecting hard drive...but SeaTools passes the drive

Tags: hard-drive, boot

Im having a difficult time trying to figure this out.

I formatted and reinstalled Windows 7 64 bit and on the next boot, it froze in the POST "detecting AHCI Port 0". I disconnected the drive and rebooted and boots (to nothing because the drive is out and my OS is on that drive). I went ahead and unplugged the HDD SATA so the BIOS wouldn't freeze,  and rebooted and brought up the boot device selection menu. I plugged in the HDD but I booted SeaTools for DOS.

SeaTools had no issues at all seeing the drive. I thought at this point it was going to fail the short test so I ran. In my surprise, it did not fail the short test, which basically every time I've had a bad drive, it failed the short test.

Long test also just finished passing as well so it would point that the hard drive is good. Could there be another reason the BIOS suddenly does not want to correctly detect the drive and stalls? I've switched cables and ports just in case but no difference.

Comment: It is pointless for us to speculate until it passes the long test .  A bad cable connection could cause the problems you describe.

Comment: I mentioned I both changed cables and ports to discard that. Right now its at 50% on the long test...

Comment: Right.  You changed the cables.  After words you started to run Seatools.  The act of changing the cables could have fixed the problem.

Comment: @Ramhound No. I changed the cables and it stayed on the same POST "detecting AHCI Port 0" message. It did the same thing.

Comment: I haven't seen the ""detecting AHCI Port 0"" error.  Have you tried another drive?

Comment: How about you try writing zeros to the drive, seatoolks ma have that option.. Another thing you can do is delete the partitions and restart(even without windows on the drive), and see if POST freezes.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are not required to load special drivers for your disk, when you're done with your disk test (which you may as well finish), note that your question implies you may have an unclean partition layout.

A format doesn't wipe partition layouts, which Windows will care about but SeaTools should not). This is just one idea so all the advice is the same:

- In response to hanging on POST due to small anomalies and changes to disk geometry (at the beginning and especially end of the disk): [Clean the disk](https://superuser.com/a/295210/392284). The linked article in the question refers to an answer by "[RU] Ivan" who says that "disk geometry for the disk is determined by the ending CHS value for the first partition" and seems related to the initial 100MB partition being smaller than 8GB on certain systems/chipsets.
- In response to "No drives found": [Clean the disk](https://superuser.com/a/477882/392284). In the same question [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/857349/392284) also concludes broken partition table.
- In response to BIOS okay, but Windows can't see it: [Use diskpart to 'clean all'](http://forums.penny-arcade.com/discussion/116550/win-7-installer-wont-recognize-hard-drive). The comment immediately after that answer says they also had a broken partition table.
- In response to PC hangs at Windows installer autodetect: [Use diskpart, clean the disk](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/258159-32-solved-hangs-auto-detect-ahci-drive-help)

Comment: I want to clarify that I have NEVER had this issue on this PC installing Windows 7 32bits. It seems strange to me that it is a Windows issue when the BIOS is what gets stuck. Ill go ahead and AGAIN format the disk but...

Comment: Intresting. Cleaned the disk in Seatools like mentioned and it passes the detection.

Comment: ...unless you've already dropped the partition tables, which is done before formatting the partitions. Note that the first option (which I edited in an attempt to be more clear) indicates that the BIOS may be attempting to calculate disk geometry based on the first partition.

Comment: I did a minute or two erase on SeaTools. Its the system drive and there is no sensitive data. Im gonna reinstall Windows. Lets hope it doesnt happen a second time...