# Does Windows 7 require the Disk 0 Partition 1 : System Reserved Partition

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can the Windows 7 system reserved partition be deleted without problems?](https://superuser.com/questions/74980/can-the-windows-7-system-reserved-partition-be-deleted-without-problems)

While installing Windows 7, I see that there's a "Disk 0 Partition 1 : System Reserved" partition with Total Space as 100 MB and Free Space as 71 MB. I never created that partition manually, and while deleting it, it gives a warning that it might contain system files, etc. Is that partition really necessary? Because Windows 7 already has limitation on the number of partitions.

Thanks.

EDIT: Just forgot to mention, the type is shown as "System".

Comment: It sounds like your using dynamic partitions.  If that is the case this partition does not count against your limit.  Of course you would be a fool to partition your hdd a great deal because frankly you are then less likely to backup your system.

Comment: If you format the entire drive NTFS (single partition) before installing Windows 7 it will not create the system partition during installation.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it out, by deleting it you wont be able to boot into windows on restart. So avoid doing so. :)

[This](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/146694-partition-extended-logical-drives.html) link might help you by creating an extended partition.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.