# Deleting Windows 7 System Reserved Partition

Tags: windows-7

Is there a way to delete the system reserved partition on windows 7 after the OS is installed? I know it is possible to not install it at all, but I am working with an image and it would be easier to delete it then re-image rather than install the OS and all the software from scratch. Our provisioning system requires a certain partitioning scheme and windows 7 breaks it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes you can remove the system reserved partition on Windows 7 after the OS installed. When you delete the system reserved partition after the OS is installed you will lose the bootfiles and  Windows 7 won't boot. You would need to run Windows 7 Startup repair after you do this.

Detailed instructions for removal of system reserved partition here:
http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/71363-system-reserved-partition-delete.html

How to run the Startup repair in Windows 7 here:
http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/681-startup-repair.html

If I were you then I would try it out in a test system first and then proceed with it in actual system.

Comment: Thank you! Great answer and resources. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Ok, I finally got around to doing this (was working on other projects)
Unfortunately, the partition numbers remain as 2 and 3 for the 2 partitions I need to keep. I need them to start at partition 1

Comment: I had to run a System repair after removing the system-reserved Partition on a drive which still had a Windows 8 Installation on it, was mounted on `D:`, and was not used as the System Partition any more. The  machine wouldn't boot any more although using `diskpart` I only made changes to `D:`, not to `C:`. Anyway, System repair fixed the Problem easily.

Comment: What if you delete the Windows 7 system reserved partition, and thereafter install some Linux distribution as a second OS in the hard disk? Could you boot Windows then by using Grub boot manager installed along with the Linux distribution?

Comment: you don't have to run startup repair, you can run the bcdboot command eg `bcdboot c:\windows /s c:`

Answer (score 3):

You could use a Linux live boot CD, like [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop). Once running, you can "Disk Utility" or Gparted for a GUI tool, or you can use 'parted' at the command line to remove the partition.

Comment: That's a good idea! I'm pretty familiar with simple linux formatting so I might have to give that a go. I have to get all of the images set up, so it will be a few days before I can do this, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

Not with the Disk Management snap-in, but third-party partition-programs can delete it.

Alternately, you can boot into Windows 7 System Recovery and delete it with `diskpart`: [[1]](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/71363-system-reserved-partition-delete.html)[[2]](http://www.computerforums.org/forums/computer-software-articles/how-remove-100mb-windows-7-system-reserved-partition-207875.html).

Of course since the system partition is where the bootloader is, you will need to then [place it onto the Windows partition](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/681-startup-repair.html) (which can also be done from the System Recovery console).