# How to install Grub2 to multi boot two Windows 7 for booting from two different HDDs?

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot, bootloader, grub2

I own a HP DV7 laptop that supports 2 HDDs.
I have installed Windows 7 on each HDDs separately, each one with their own bootloaders, who do not communicate with each other.

The problem is that when I want to switch through the operational systems I must change the HDDs cables inside the laptop manually. HP (inside their forum) has reported that its a known BIOS fault but they never corrected it.

I have read on the same forum that this could be corrected installing Grub2 to load the Windows 7 partitions. I do not want to install any linux distro on my laptop and I want to use the Grub2 for solving my dual boot problem. I have searched for an installer but I didn't found it yet. Someone knows a way for solving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your laptop uses BIOS you can install grub, but if it has UEFI it can be very hard to build it into an existing installation. The internet tells me that EasyBCD cannot be used with UEFI so I assume you have a BIOS laptop (or UEFI in legacy mode, works the same). Before you do anything, be sure that you don't Hibernate but do a normal shutdown and FastBoot must be disabled on both W7 installations (FastBoot doesn't go well with multiboot systems, better not enable it after grub installed).
You can install grub, but you probably have a hidden partition (W7 and up always installs that if you partition your disk in Windows setup) which you need to remove. Before you do that I suggest you make an image of your entire disks with CloneZilla (or any other tool that does this). After you make the backups you can follow instructions linked from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/448640/deleting-windows-7-system-reserved-partition). If both installations still work you can slightly re-size a partition on one disk (if needed) and install grub.

Edit: You don't have to delete the system reserved partitions per se anymore. Nowadays Grub can handle that. Read more [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Windows_installed_in_BIOS-MBR_mode)

Answer (score 0):

I'v found a temporary solution installing EasyBCD on a USB Flash and using it to prompt to boot the two operational Systems.