# is it possible to install windows 7 independently on each of these two hard drives in this situation?

Tags: windows-7

I have a laptop. Dell E7440.

It has two drives in there.

Here is a picture of the relevant part of the bottom of such a laptop.

[image]

One of the drives is a 2.5" and the other is a card (mSATA card).

They are both 240GB drives.

I'd like to install windows 7 independently on each of these two hard drives. I'll explain what I mean independently.

I mean that I don't want a boot menu on one of them pointing to the other one. i.e. I don't want a situation where only one of the drives has an active partition.

I want it to be the case that I choose in the BIOS/UEFI which drive to boot from.

But here's the issue..

I have no screwdriver in this place I am currently in!!

Normally when I want to do it I ensure that the only hard drive plugged in is the one I want to install Windows on.

But I can't do that here because I don't have a screwdriver!

The other thing I have sometimes done in the past, is gone to the BIOS and disabled any hard drive that I don't currently want to install Windows on.

But this BIOS/UEFI doesn't have that!

This is an image of the BIOS/UEFI (incase if looks familiar to anybody and they know of an option to disable drives! I don't mean choosing what device to boot off of, of course it has that, but I mean disabling drives so e.g. saying SATA-0 is disabled or SATA-1 is disabled)

[image]

I booted off a Win7 installation USB, and picked a drive to install to. Installed that. then I booted off the Win7 installation USB again, and picked the other drive to install to.

What it did was set up this system

[image]

So you see it didn't set up the drives the same way..

By right clicking each "Disk" in disk management, and choosing properties

Disk0 is my 2.5" drive.

Disk1 is my card drive.

Disk0/2.5" drive,  has two partitions, the 100MB one and the main one, and I suppose it's that disk, disk0, that is the one where it put the boot menu.

Disk1 has one partition.

If I do msconfig you see the boot menu I have (note- I used bcdedit to edit the descriptions to make the descriptions a bit more clear so it doesn't just say "1. Windows 7   2. Windows 7")

[image]

If I go to the BIOS/UEFI and choose to boot off of the card, then that won't work, and it's clear why.. If looking at the disk management screen, you see it's not an active partition. The only active partition among the two drives is the 100MB partition on the 2.5" drive.

So it's booting off the 2.5" drive and the boot menu has two options, one Windows 7 that runs on that same 2.5" drive, and the other that is on the card.

The one I it starts me up into is C, which is good though i'd still want to boot directly so the drives are independent.  So that I could unplug one and run off the other and so on.

Here are two more pics re the situation at the moment

[image]

[image]

I want both independent. I want each drive to have an active partition, each drive to be able to boot Windows 7.  No boot menu. And i'd choose in the BIOS/UEFI which one to boot from.

I wouldn't normally have a problem setting that up, but, in the location I am in, I have no screwdriver. And the UEFI/BIOS has no option to disable drives either.

So, i'm wondering if anybody here has any ideas re if it's possible to do the kind of setup that I am looking for, given those two limitations I mentioned in the above paragraph?!

Comment: You can easily disconnect the cable connected to the 2.5" drive but that won't allow you to disconnect the m.2 drive.  You need a screwdriver to do what you want.

Comment: The other option would be to install both and fiddle with the boot menus manually

Comment: @JourneymanGeek well I have installed on both drives, but I think both drives might need windows to install itself with a 100MB partition on them?

Comment: Ah. Didn't quite think about them both being UEFI

Comment: "but, in the location I am in, I have no screwdriver." - WAT! Thats the only way (I can see) you doing what you want... you can't improvise? - tip of a knife, pliers, thin piece of metal, etc.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek they're not! they're legacy.  See https://www.eightforums.com/threads/bios-mode-see-if-windows-boot-in-uefi-or-legacy-mode.29504/       Whether UEFI or Legacy, one hard drive will have a 100MB partition on one of the hard drives. But if with UEFI, then it will be labelled EFI in disk management.  With legacy it will be marked "system reserved".

Comment: @JourneymanGeek also, UEFI or not seems like a red herring to me because either way one drive has a 100MB partition and one doesn't.  e.g. mine isn't UEFI but one has one and one doesn't. And it'd take fiddling to make that not the case.. e.g. to enesure neither has it or that both have it.

Comment: btw I do have an idea.. I remember the ancient partition magic had a hide partition option.. maybe  gparted has such an option.. that could work..since the first one it installs to has the 100MB partition so it'd give both that.. i think, though would have to test

Comment: hiding seems like a non option but given https://www.terabyteunlimited.com/kb/kb-articles/how-to-remove-the-windows-system-reserved-partition/ and https://superuser.com/questions/448640/deleting-windows-7-system-reserved-partition  maybe it's possible to use the startup repair or recovery console, get boot files on each.. also set each drive to have an active partition.  great link here https://www.hanselman.com/blog/switching-my-windows-7-boot-disk-from-d-to-c-with-bcdboot-rather-than-bcdedit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that the BCD(boot configuration data), doesn't have to go on the/a 100MB partition, it can go on the partition that has Windows.

It's even possible to delete the 100MB partition, and make the windows partition active and put the BCD on that.

Deleting the 100MB partition is mentioned here [Deleting Windows 7 System Reserved Partition](https://superuser.com/questions/448640/deleting-windows-7-system-reserved-partition)  but I solved this, without deleting the 100MB partition.

This link has the solution. Scott Hanselman(author at that link), had a different issue to me but the same principles apply.

https://www.hanselman.com/blog/switching-my-windows-7-boot-disk-from-d-to-c-with-bcdboot-rather-than-bcdedit

Supposing as is his case and my case, I have c:\windows that is not bootable, in the sense of, doesn't have boot configuration data. Then and so, I did,

`bcdboot c:\windows /s c:`

(That bcdboot's /s is "Specifies an optional volume letter parameter to designate the target system partition where boot environment files are")

(side note, that /s is not syntactically that like the /s the old format command had to make it system.. cos that one didn't take a drive letter after it, but it is a bit like it though but the other way like /s c: rather than c: /s!. And of course the format command had to format and this bcdboot command doesn't. The bcdboot command with /s, is a bit like the sys command on DOS systems where you'd do `sys c:` to put boot files there. though here the command is bcdboot and it takes a windows directory and a drive letter, and you add a /s before the drive letter)

And in disk management, setting that Windows partition to Active. (one partition per drive can be active).  (Right click the partition and click "mark partition as active")

And that sorted it out.

And I removed any entries I could from the boot menu i.e. the boot menu on the 2.5" drive referenced itself, and the card. I removed the entry for the card, leaving just the unremovable entry, itself. So the boot menu on the 2.5" drive only has the option of booting itself. And then it goes straight in no boot menu.

So now the 2.5" drive and the card are independent. I use the UEFI/BIOS to choose which to boot off of.