# Moving system reserved to C:

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have a bit of trouble here trying to move system reserved (F) to (C), so that my OS can operate independently without the need of the other partition.

Tried using BCDboot/easybcd, but if I remove the hdd which has the system reserved, windows wouldn't boot.

Here is a screenshot of disk manager:

[image]
W7 x64 ultimate english

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could be a [duplicate](http://superuser.com/questions/920744/use-system-reserved-partition-to-create-another-partition)

Answer (score 0):

Before you continue: **BACKUP YOUR DATA AND PROCEED AT YOUR OWN RISK**.

**Possible Solution:** Shrink the existing `C:` partition and create enough space for an extra partition on the same disk. **Copy** (DO NOT MOVE) all files from the original *System Reserved*. Disconnect (or disable) all other drives leaving the one with Windows, boot from a Windows Installation disk and run `BootRec` with all fixes.

**Real Solution:** Format drive prior to install Windows, or format with `DiskPart` command-line tool while installing without using the setup guide. As expected this requires a start-from-scratch boot-from-DVD/USB reload of Windows. In-place upgrade done within a working Windows using a system image or installation disk **will not work**.

On a side note: It is not recommended to have boot partition and system partition merged into a single one.